# Time Machine spontaneously stopped working

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, error

As of today, I can no longer create Time Machine backups. I'm getting error 92.

After googling it, I ejected my disk, restarted my computer and tried again, but it still isn't working. The last successful backup occurred two days ago.

I haven't updated the OS or any apps in the meantime, and my computer and the external drive I use for Time Machine have not moved from their places on my desk since then.

Update: Ran diagnostics / disk first aid with Disk Utility on both my internal drive and my external drive. Both came out fine. Tried opening a file to check whether the data was corrupted. File opened without issue. After this, the backup took a while but was successful. Only thing I can think of is my Mac *thought* it couldn’t read the drive but when I forced it to realise it could it gave me ni more trouble.

Comment: You can try doing a First Aid on TM Volume with Disk Utility. If it's always broken, you can try open Console, find "backupd" in search zone, then start a backup . You may have more details on problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! // Ran a first aid, and no problems were found with the external drive. // What am I looking for in Console? "backupd" returns a bunch of results which say things I don't understand.

Comment: Can you see an error message when the save stop?

Comment: Yeah, error 92. But it’s working now for some reason (will update my question).

Comment: Happy for you. ;)